Is there any way to automate the entire ML/data visualization process workflow using only verbal instructions on LangChain or other OpenAI APIs?
I intend to use Open AI APIs/Plugins for an application to automate the entire ML workflow that includes image classification and rule based systems to generate a generic recommendation and intelligent generation of insights based on the results of the data.
I have found an example of implementation via YouTube, but isn't sure how it can be used for tailored applications.
import os
import sys

import openai
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain, RetrievalQA
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader, TextLoader
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
from langchain.indexes.vectorstore import VectorStoreIndexWrapper
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

import constants

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = constants.APIKEY

# Enable to save to disk & reuse the model (for repeated queries on the same data)
PERSIST = False

query = None
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  query = sys.argv[1]

if PERSIST and os.path.exists("persist"):
  print("Reusing index...\n")
  vectorstore = Chroma(persist_directory="persist", embedding_function=OpenAIEmbeddings())
  index = VectorStoreIndexWrapper(vectorstore=vectorstore)
else:
  #loader = TextLoader("data/data.txt") # Use this line if you only need data.txt
  loader = DirectoryLoader("data/")
  if PERSIST:
    index = VectorstoreIndexCreator(vectorstore_kwargs={"persist_directory":"persist"}).from_loaders([loader])
  else:
    index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])

chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
  llm=ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo"),
  retriever=index.vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1}),
)

chat_history = []
while True:
  if not query:
    query = input("Prompt: ")
  if query in ['quit', 'q', 'exit']:
    sys.exit()
  result = chain({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})
  print(result['answer'])

  chat_history.append((query, result['answer']))
  query = None

I am not familiar with the implementation and whether it's feasible to use the plugins, so any advice will be welcomed.
